# Question on non-atomic measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a finite measure space.  Call $\mu$ nonatomic if for any $A\in\Sigma$ with $\mu(A)>0$ there exists $B\in\Sigma$ with $B\subset A$ and $0<\mu(B)<\mu(A)$.

> Suppose that $\mathcal S$ be the algebra that generates  $\Sigma$. I am asking to what is the relation between nonatomicity of $\mu$ and $\mu|_\mathcal S$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There are multiple algebras that can generate a given $\sigma$ algebra, including the $\sigma$ algebra itself.

Comment: I think the question calls for some sort of transfinite induction, so it doesn't matter whether the generating algebra (or whatever) is unique. But algebra is sufficiently strong to allow for pretty much any type of argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fact **. If  $\mu$ is non-atomic then so is $\mu|_{S}$.

**Proof.** Assume the contrary and let $\mu|_{S}$ is atomic. Then there will be a set(atom) 
$A \in S$ with $\mu(A)>0$ such that for each element of the $S$ with $B \subseteq A$ we have $\mu|_{S}(B)=0$ or $\mu|_{S}(B)=\mu|_{S}(A)$. Since $\mu$ is non-atomic and extension of $\mu|_{S}$ by the condition $\mu(A)=\mu|_{S}(A)$ we claim that there is $B_0 \in \sum$ such that $0<\mu(B_0)<\mu(A)$. By the Charatheodory measure extension theorem from the algebra to the minimal algebra we have
$
\mu(B_0)= \inf \{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mu|_{S}(A_k) : A_k \in S \& k \in N \& 
$
$
B_0 \subseteq \cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k \in S\}.
$
For $\epsilon=((\mu(A)-\mu(B_0))/2$ there is a sequence $\{ A_k \in S:k \in N\}$ such that  $B_0 \subseteq \cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k \in S$ and $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)<\mu(B_0)+\epsilon$. Then we have:

(i) $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}A_k\cap A \in S$;

(ii) $\mu|_{S}(\cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k\cap A)=\mu(\cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k\cap A) \le \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_k)<\mu(B_0)+\epsilon < \mu(A)=\mu|_{S}(A)$;

(iii)  $\mu|_{S}(\cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k\cap A)=\mu(\cup_{k =1}^{\infty}A_k\cap A)\ge \mu(B_0)>0$;

So The conditions (i)-(iii) contradicts to the our assumption that $A$ is atom for $\mu|_{S}$.

****Example( The converse of the Fact above is not valid).** We have to show there is $S$ and $\mu$ such that $\mu|_{S}$ is non-atomic but  $\mu$ is atomic. Indeed, let consider $E=Q\cap[0,1]$ where $Q$ is a set of all rational numbers; $\sum=\{A:A\subseteq E\}$. Let $(q_k)_{k \in N}$ be  a numeration of the $E$; Let $m_k$ be a sequence of positive numbers with $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m_k=1$. For $A \in \sum$ we set $\mu(A)=\sum_{q_k \in A}m_k$.
Let $S$ be a class of subsets of $E$ which can be presented in the form 
 $\sum_{k=1}^n[a_k,b_k[\cap Q , (n\in N)$, where $\{[a_k,b_k[:1 \le k \le n\}$ is a sequence of pairwise disjoint intervals closed from the left and open from the right. Then it is not hard to show that

(j)  $S$ is an algebra of subsets of $E$ which generates $\sum$;

(jj) $\mu$ is atomic measure on $\sum$;

(jjj) $\mu|_{S}$ is non-atomic measure on $S$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no measure theory wizard, so check my argument well for errors!

Consider the collection of sets $\mathcal A\subset\Sigma$ defined by: $A\in\mathcal A$ if and only if the following two conditions both hold

1. $\mu(A)=0$ or $\exists B\in\Sigma:0<\mu(B)<\mu(A)$.
2. $\mu(A^c)=0$ or $\exists B\in\Sigma:0<\mu(B)<\mu(A^c)$.

If we assume that $\mu|_\mathcal S$ is 'nonatomic', then $\mathcal A$ is a [Dynkin class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynkin_system) containing $\mathcal S$ (check this! I found the second definition found on Wikipedia to be simplest to work with). Since $\mathcal S$ is clearly stable under finite intersections, it follows from Dynkin's Lemma that $\Sigma\subset \mathcal A$.

Comment: It is required that $\mathcal S$ is algebra not $\sigma$-algebra.Your Dynkin class is $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: In order to use Dynkin's Lemma, you only need $\mathcal S$ to be intersection stable - as any algebra is.